# Cocoa application with cocos2d-iphone?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I'd like to do this:

Create a Cocoa application with a couple NSButtons in it. Also, a "cocos2d-iphone" view running in the same window.

If I trigger the NSButtons, a function is called in the cocos2d-iphone view (not sure where, maybe in the currently running scene?).

Well, I managed to create a new project from the cocos2d-iphone for Mac template, made the window bigger than the cocos2d view, moved the cocos2d view, and added my NSButtons. Now, I am not very sure about how to make the connection I need.. =/

Answer (score 1):

I suggest reading an Interface Builder tutorial. [This one](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_quick_start/020-Tutorial_Designing_a_User_Interface_with_Interface_Builder/interface_builder_tutorial.html) is using Quartz, it's not Cocos2D but close enough. Simply assume the Quartz view to be Cocos2D view while you go through the tutorial.

Note that Cocos2D/EAGLView has some issues with NSView objects. In particular you can't add NSView objects as subviews to the Cocos2D OpenGL view, they will simply not be displayed. This is a general problem of the OpenGL view on Mac, and there are solutions/workarounds for this but they unfortunately do not work with Cocos2D. So if you're planning to have NSView objects overlapping the Cocos2D view … well, you can try and if you can make it work, PLEASE let me know how! :)